# Woocommerce. Showcase with ajax loading of categories and products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I Use the latest WP, WC and Storefront Theme versions. On the showcase page, I need to display all categories with products. For example, Bed Category: bed 1, bed 2, bed 3 ..., chairs of the following category: chair 1, chair 2, ... etc. I want to implement the following, or / or a) load a display case with 4 products in each category, after the first scroll, Ajax will download the next 4-8-12 products in each category b) will download all the products of the first category, and the next categories will be loaded after scrolling.

I tried different options. The usual Ajax query works with posts, for me it doesn't work with products.

This is how I display all products by category:

```
<?php 
 $args_tax = array(
'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
'hierarchical' => 0,
'hide_empty'   => 1,
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args_tax );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
  echo '<h2>' . $cat->name . '</h2>';
  $args_prod = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => $cat -> slug,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args_prod );
woocommerce_product_loop_start();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

If I understand correctly, in case (a) (loading 4 products in each category, and then loading the rest after the scroll), I need to specify posts_per_page = 4 in args_prod, and then connect ajax. But the problem is that $ loop-> max_num_pages is always equal 1 (even if there are 30 products and posts_per_page = 4).

In the script -

```
<script>
  var ajaxurl = "<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
  var products_query = "<?php serialize($loop->query_vars) ?>";
</script>
```

I get the "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error. And then ajax does not work, because the original query is not correct. I would be grateful for a hint how to write correctly in this case?

ajax button code after category products grid

```
<div id="loadmore"Load More</div>
```

ajax handler

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#loadmore').click(function(){
        $(this).text('Loading...');
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': products_query,
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:data,
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) { 
                    let btn = '#loadmore';
                    let wrapper = '#showcase';
                    $(btn).text('Load More');
                    $(wrapper).append(data);
                }
                    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in function.php

```
function loadmore_posts(){

    $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );

    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

           while( have_posts() ): the_post();

             wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

           endwhile;

        woocommerce_product_loop_end(); 

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_posts');
```

////////////////////

In option (b) (load the first category, and after scrolling the rest), I added number = 1 to args_tax, and offset = 1 in requests, but I also don't quite understand how to write a query to the database correctly.

I would be grateful for any help or hint in the right direction.
Any thoughts on how to make it work?